# Time variables with SharePoint Designer Workflows

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, date-time

I there a way to set up set up a workflow variable or condition to find [TODAY] - 180; using SharePoint Designer?

Update:
Would using this in SharePoint designer work for finding list items 180 days before Today?

`Set Variable:VarToday to Today
then add 0 months, -180, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Variable:VarToday (Output to Variable:Var180days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Add Time to Date" workflow action, please see example below:

[image: Example of configure Add Time to Date workflow Action]

Also maybe you have a look at 3rd party solution [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) for Workflow Designer that contains 
[Get Items by Query](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/documents-list-items-processing/#GetItems) workflow action, that can query items by defined CAML expression.

P.S: This one from products are developed by my team.